# SaltStack - grains.filter_by, specify grain key and filter by sub key

Tags: salt-stack

I'm not sure if I'm wording this correctly, but I was hoping I could get an example of filtering by matching on grain keys and then filtering by values (or sub key:values). My concern is that another grain could be added some time in the future and be picked up by filter_by incorrectly. Example below...

Example list of grains:

```
Host1
    role: 
        webserver
    secondary:
        none
Host2 
    role: 
        appserver1
    secondary:
        appserver2
Host3
    role: 
        appserver1
        appserver2
    secondary:
        none
```

Example map file:

```
{% set java = salt['grains.filter_by']({
    'default': {
        'target': '/some/default/file/path',
    },
    'appserver1': {
        'target': '/app/server1/path',
    },
    'appserver2': {
        'target': '/app/server2/path',
    },
},
default='default'
)%}
```

In this example, imagine secondary was the additional grain that was added at a future time. What would the mapfile pick up for Host2 after this secondary grain is added? I know this isn't the best example, but this came up when code reviewing some states I wrote, and I didn't have a good answer as to how we can target grain keys. In this case, I would want to target the grain 'role' and filter on the values within that grain. How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I completely missed this in the docs until I read them multiple times...

Solution is to add grain value to filter on like so:

```
{% set java = salt['grains.filter_by']({
    'default': {
        'target': '/some/default/file/path',
    },
    'appserver1': {
        'target': '/app/server1/path',
    },
    'appserver2': {
        'target': '/app/server2/path',
    },
},
grain='role',
default='default'
)%}
```